# OTC Markets, OTCBB & NASDAQ Level 2

Tags: stocks, nasdaq, pink-sheets

Does [NASDAQ Level 2](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=nqds) or [NASDAQ Total View](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=Totalview2) support OTCBB stocks or only stocks listed on national exchanges?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe Nasdaq provides OTCBB quotations through those services.  The TotalView webpage says:

> TotalView, Nasdaq’s premier data feed, shows you every single quote and order at every price level in Nasdaq-, NYSE-, MKT- and regional-listed securities on Nasdaq.

The phrase "Nasdaq-, NYSE-, MKT- and regional-listed securities" does not include pink sheet stocks.